Returning an error from server action Next.js
This is my server action.
I use Drizzle for communication with my db.
Below is the simple delete User function which works fine.
'use server'

export async function deleteUser(id: number) {
  try {
    await db.delete(users).where(eq(users.id, id));
    revalidatePath("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({
      message: error instanceof Error ? error.message : "Unknown error",
    });
  }
}

And this is my client function where I invoke server action:
'use client' 

const deleteUserHandler = async (id: number) => {
    try {
      await deleteUser(id);
      toast.success(`${user.name} deleted successfully!`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error("An Error Occurred!");
    }
  };

For example, when I force Offline mode in Network tab I am getting this message in browser console:
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at fetchServerAction (server-action-reducer.js:32:23)

I don't even get error in my terminal console inside VSC.
Can somebody explain to me how can I for example  throw custom message inside the server action and display that message as alert for example in my client component?
